# I created a correlation between content-size and background-size. Why?

Tags: html, css, sass

**Hey Guys**
I am creating a website for class. I just added a small linear gradient to blend from the background-image to the background-color. The background is in defined in the :root so I used :root:before to add the gradient. On a page with enough content, everything works just fine. But on pages with less content, the background-image is small and grows with the quantity of content.
I have no heccing idea why.

The SCSS

```css
:root {
   background: $background-color;
   /*Absolut verlinktes Bild*/
   background-image: url(http://w4.wallls.com/uploads/original/201711/23/wallls.com_163130.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;

   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 1.1rem;
   font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
:root:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -15%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background: linear-gradient(to top, $background-color, transparent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit isn't the `background-image`, but the `root` itself. Because you don't have any content inside it, and the *default width & height* of `root` grow with ***content inside it***. You can do the following-

```css
:root {
   min-width: 100vw;
   min-height: 100vh; 
   background: $background-color;
   /*Absolut verlinktes Bild*/
   background-image: url(http://w4.wallls.com/uploads/original/201711/23/wallls.com_163130.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;

   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 1.1rem;
   font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
:root:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -15%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background: linear-gradient(to top, $background-color, transparent);
}
```

Comment: Your help brang me way closer to my destination! thxx

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Sapinder, I developed this solution. Using min-width and min-height is a heccing good idea. But since the scrollbar must be subtracted from the min-width to work, to prevent x overflow, I had to create a small calculation inside a variable.
Also, I had to change the background-size from "contain" to 100% to always fill the whole background.
I don't know if this is the best or most elegant way to style a background but it works (except for the gradient but that wasn't part of the question.)
New SCSS:

```
$background-color: #344451;
$scrollbar-width: 5px; /*Only use a variable for this sure to accessibility of the number*/
$background-min-width: calc(100vw-$scrollbar-width); /*Substract the width of the scrollbar from the minimal background width.*/

:root {
   min-width: $background-min-width;
   min-height: 100vh;
   background: $background-color;
   /*Absolut verlinktes Bild*/
   background-image: url(http://w4.wallls.com/uploads/original/201711/23/wallls.com_163130.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100%;

   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 1.1rem;
   font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
:root:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -15%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background: linear-gradient(to top, $background-color, transparent);
}
```